# Getting specific controller viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to ASP.net having been a PHP coder for 10 years. The MVC makes sense to be as I find it quite similar to [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

I am trying to find the best solution for storing and serving meta data to my web pages in my ASP.net MVC 4 project. From what I have read I have concluded to use the following method.

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace project.Models
{
    public class Meta
    {
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public String Keywords { get; set; }
        public String H1 { get; set; }
        public String H2 { get; set; }
        public String Robots { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace project.Controllers
{
    public class AboutController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["metaTitle"] = "About us";
            ViewData["metaDescription"] = "";
            ViewData["metaKeywords"] = "";
            ViewData["pageH1"] = "About";
            ViewData["PageH2"] = "";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>project | @ViewData["metaTitle"]</title>
<meta name="description" content="@ViewData["metaDescription"]">
<meta name="keywords" content="@ViewData["metaKeywords"]">
<meta name="robots" content="@ViewData["metaRobots"]">
```

The problem I have actually comes in one of my other views where I am trying to build a breadcrumb trail. At the moment I can get the controller/action name to appear in the breadcrumb, however **I wish to access the view data for those controller/actions**.

I can't find anywhere that explains how to do it/if it is possible.

Therefore;

- Either I am going about storing meta data wrong, if so tell me a better way to do it.
- else please outline a way to access a controllers ViewData

*Please provide code samples or resources that accurately explain how to do it*

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: ViewData will store data for single request only(in your case whenever you access about section). But as per my understanding you want that data for whole application(pages). I would suggest to use Session instead of ViewData.

Comment: How that got 2 upvotes I'll never understand. Please, don't use the session for stuff like this. Ironically, this is pretty much the only truly acceptable thing to use `ViewData`/`ViewBag` for. However, Anupam is right that you can't get the view data for anything but the currently requested controller action.

Comment: If you need to get those data for multiple different controller actions, your best bet is to persist your `Meta` class with some link to the action it applies to so you can look it up at a later point. Then, in each action, you can query for the `Meta` instance that applies to it, as well as any other `Meta` instances you need.

Answer (score -1):

I would do something like below,

1) Create a base class model and this base model will be derived in other models.

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Keywords { get; set; }
    public String H1 { get; set; }
    public String H2 { get; set; }
    public String Robots { get; set; }
}
```

> About Model class

```
public class AboutModel : BaseModel
{
    public string AboutDescription { get; set; }
}
```

2) Create a Intialize method in BaseController class which will set the properites for Title and description for your model.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseModel Initialize(BaseModel model)
    {
        model.Title = "Title";
        model.Description = "Desc";
        return model;
    }
}
```

3) In About controller, you would need to call the initialize method like below.

```
public class AboutController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //create instance for About Model
        var model = new AboutModel();
        Initialize(model);
        model.AboutDescription = "About Description";

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

4) In _Layout.cshtml class you need to use the BaseModel class

```
@model <YourNameSpace>.BaseModel

<title>@Model.Title</title>
```

5) Other views ex : About.cshtml

```
@model <YourNameSpace>.AboutModel
```

I would recommend not to use ViewData for handling Common site properties like Title / Meta tags. This way your code will be much cleaner...

Since you are deriving the base class model to the other views and Initializing the Initialize method in all the ActionResults method you should get the title description properties across the pages / views.

Comment: It's actually a *very* bad idea to have your layout declare a model. Storing these type of things in `ViewData`/`ViewBag` is perfectly acceptable, and actually preferable as they won't kill your app if you neglect to declare them, or have a view model where you need to inherit from something other than this base model, or you have a view that doesn't require a model at all.

Comment: @Chris I read somewhere that using ViewData / ViewBag is not a good practice

Comment: The problem is that it is abused and used more often than it should be and in scenarios where it should not be. It's perfectly fine for thing s like filling in the title tag for the page or a description meta tag. Where it's bad practice is when you start try to store something other than a simple value type in it like select lists, or  even entire models.